# Обращение к массиву через global - ресурсозатратная операция?

Tags: php, массивы, php7, процессор

Имеется демонизированный скрипт на PHP 7.3.
В цикле необходимо запускать функцию, которая обращается к большому ассоциативному массиву через модификатор global:

```
global $array;
```

Было замечено, что как только в функции появляется эта срока, скрипт увеличивает потребление ядра процессора до 95%. Пробовал также вариант передачи переменной массива через параметр функции:

```
function test(&$array) {}
```

Результат тот же самый. Нагрузка на процессор повышается очень заметно и замедляет выполнение скрипта.
Подскажите, есть какие-нибудь варианты обратиться к массиву в функции без такого замедления? Может быть, существуют какие-либо настройки для PHP, исправляющие поведение?

Comment: Можно ещё получать доступ с помощью массива `$GLOBALS['array']`, но наверное результат будет такой же.

Comment: Проблема скорее всего не в global, а в самом коде, который так или иначе приводит к многократному копированию уже заполненного массива.

Comment: Нет, массив не копируется, есть только многократное обращение через global. Как я писал, достаточно добавить строчку "global $array;", и выполнение сразу же замедляется без какого-либо дополнительного кода.

Comment: Вариант с использованием `$GLOBALS['array']`, как посоветовал @Эдуард, работает нормально.